# How to surpess php warnings?

Tags: php, warnings

I'm have a problem supressing php warnings - they keep showing up on my php pages. For example, this one:

```
Strict Standards: Non-static method MyTimer::instance() should not be called statically in C:\eclipse-php\workspace\web\mypackage\classes\Timer.class.php on line 270
```

I'm using xampp, and modified php.ini to include this directive:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_STRICT
```

and restart apache, but it makes no differences.

Any suggestions?

Comment: search your code for any calls to error_reporting. It is likely that something is changing the setting at runtime.

Comment: You should never suppress them - they're indications of problems to come. You should code to handle them.

Comment: You can probably just make that function static.

Comment: it's a 3rd party package - I prefer not to change the code if possible.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn your suggestion worked - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, you should correct the error, but you can disable the error message also quite simple:

`ini_set('display_errors', '0');     # don't show any errors...
 error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);  # ...but do log them in apache log`

set this code in your *.php file for example "index.php"

more information:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

I hope it works fine for you

Grezz Dave